# Getting black image while taking screenshot of videos c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, screenshot

I have used the below code for taking screenshots in c# and it worked. However when I tried to take screenshots when a video is played, I am getting only black pixels for the video part and the rest of the screen is captured.
Please could anyone help me on this.

Here's my code :

```
    String filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Temp.Jpeg");
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
    bitmap.Save("Temp.Jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    System.IO.FileStream Imagestream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
```

Also please may I know why I am getting these black pixels?

Comment: There can be a good help on site http://www.mvps.org/vbdx/articles/screenshot/index.html which is about that opengl rendered surfaces dont being captured by standard graphics copyfromscreen.

Comment: Thanks @Independent for the link.Could you please advise me what is the reason for this black pixels only for videos?

Comment: I'm not well-known to the reason behind this rather then there is a overlay given by grapåhic card on opengl applications (you will notice the same black/white screens to some 3D games, depends on their graphic settings). Hopefully there are peoples out there who know all details for you. Also I see that your question is well duplicated here on SO.